# Cast objects to an interface they don't implement but having the same method signature

Tags: java, jdbc, casting, dry, autocloseable

Please take a look at the following `DbUtil` class example. Here are three its methods

```
public static void closeResults(ResultSet rs) {
    if (rs != null) {
        try {
            if (!rs.isClosed()){
                rs.close();
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
}

public static void closeStatement(Statement stmt) {
    if(stmt != null) {
        try {
            if (!stmt.isClosed()) {
                stmt.close();
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
}

public static void closeConnection(Connection conn) {
    if(conn != null) {
        try {
            if(!conn.isClosed()) {
                conn.close();    
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see all 3 methods have identical logic, and I would like to make this code DRY. A new common method can be written like this

```
public static void closeStatement(AutoCloseable ob) {
    if(ob != null) {
        try {
            ob.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
}
```

`AutoCloseable` interface doesn't contain `isClosed` method. But it is still a good practice (or even must do) to perform that check before trying to close a resource. Am I right? Can the code be simplified somehow and still perform `isClosed` check?

NOTE. This is just an example of the problem. I know that `AutoCloseable` interface is designed for try-with-resources technic and thus the code can be rewritten with that style and `DbUtil` won't be required anymore. But I would like to clarify for myself is it even possible to do something in a similar case. For example, I would think about creating some interface, say, `MyAutoCloseable`, extending `AutoCloseable` one and having `isClosed` method, but sure that won't work, because it wouldn't be possible to cast `ResultSet` or `Statement` to `MyAutoCloseable`.

Comment: you can do such things using reflection. but be carefull. java is designed to invoke methods on type you know they exists (because the compiler checks many things). using reflection, you break the compiler, you break encapsulation and many more things, and you will pay the cost one day.

Comment: If you just want to use with these 3 objects, JavaDoc says: if the `close()` method is called on a closed object is, the call is a "no-op"...

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to call `isClosed()` at all. Every `close()` method I have ever seen in the JDK for 20 years is idempotent, meaning you can call it twice or more without harm.

Comment: Except `AutoCloseable#close`. From the documentation: <p>Note that unlike the {@link java.io.Closeable#close close} method of {@link java.io.Closeable}, this {@code close} method is <em>not</em> required to be idempotent.  In other words, calling this {@code close} method more than once may have some visible side effect, unlike {@code Closeable.close} which is required to have no effect if called more than once.

Comment: But, finally, `AutoCloseable` was designed to be auto-closed, thus, obviously, it was not the best example in my question.

Comment: And all that would be obviated by using `Closeable`.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it using reflection.

```
public static void close(Object obj)
{
    try
    {
        Class<?> c = obj.getClass();
        Method isClosed = c.getDeclaredMethod("isClosed");// No I18N
        if( (Boolean)isClosed.invoke(obj) )
        {
            Method close = c.getDeclaredMethod("close");
            close.invoke(obj);
        }
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```